# Google OAuth in a WPF Application: avoid external browser error response

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth, google-oauth

I developed Google OAuth 2 Login in a C# desktop application, using the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications).

It works but, after login, Google redirects to http://localhost:randomport and external browser respond with "Hmm, we can't reach this page.".

How can avoid it?

I don't want to change redirect URL and I prefer to not manage an HTTP Listener (in a random port?!?): I just want avoid that browser shows this error.

Thank you.

**Edit**: Same code in some other PCs works! :o

Comment: In the steps of the official tutorial, did you follow the steps for Web Application, or Windows 8.1 Application? I think you may have used the steps for Web Applications. But since yours is a desktop application, you should be following the steps for Windows 8.1 application (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#windows-81-applications).

Comment: I followed the steps for Installed applications.